# Storing players turn

Tags: javascript

I have to do a trivia game for only two players in JavaScript.
Depending on which "box" they fall after throwing the dice, the rules are:

1. They have to answer a question; if they answer correctly, they stay
   in that place; otherwise they have to go back two places.
2. They lose a turn.
3. Answer correctly three out of five questions: if answered correctly, throw dice and advance the given number, if answered wrong, go back that number.
4. Answer one question correctly and advance two boxes, otherwise stay
   in place.
5. Automatically advance two places.

Which do you think is the best way to store whose turn it is?
I was thinking in using something like this ["Inheritance and the prototype chain"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain#Different_ways_to_create_objects_and_the_resulting_prototype_chain) but I'm not quite sure on how to use it, as I haven't learned it yet. 
Any ideas? Thanks! :D

Comment: `var whoseTurnIsIt = "player1";`, `var player1sTurn = true;`, `var activePlayer = 1;` are all valid ways of doing it, and there are many more. It's entirely up to you what works best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to do that with prototypes, you could create a player object like this:

```
function Player() {
    this.position = 0; //the player's current position starts at zero
    this.questionsCorrect = 0; //number of questions this player has answered
}
Player.prototype.move = function(spaces) { //use prototype to give ALL player objects a "move" function
    this.position += spaces; //increment the player's position
}
```

You honestly shouldn't need objects for a game that simple, but that should leave plenty of room for expansion.  Now, you need some code to manage the game.

```
//make two new players
var player1 = new Player();
var player2 = new Player();

var currentPlayer = player1; //it starts as player 1's turn
```

Now, you need a game loop.

```
function gameStep() {
    for (var i=0; i<5; i++) { //your outline doesn't really make sense, but I assume you want each player to be asked 5 questions at a time
        var result = askQuestionTo(currentPlayer); //ask a question to whomever's turn it is

        if (result==answer) {
            currentPlayer.questionsCorrect += 1; //increment correct counter for this player
        }
        else {
            currentPlayer.move(-2); //move two backwards if incorrect
            //you talk about "losing a turn", but that doesn't really make sense here.
            //please clarify.
        }
    }

    var diceRoll = 1+Math.floor(Math.random()*12); //calculate a random dice number
    if (currentPlayer.questionsCorrect>=3) {
        currentPlayer.move(diceRoll); //if at least three correct, move forward    
    }
    else {
        currentPlayer.move(-diceRoll); //otherwise, move backward
    }

    currentPlayer.move(2); //you said that the player moves forward two regardless

    currentPlayer.questionsCorrect = 0;

    currentPlayer = currentPlayer==player1?player2:player1; //it's the other player's turn
}
```

You must implement askQuestion to ask a player some question, and you must somehow replace answer with the correct answer (possibly from an array.)  Now, you have to call gameStep() repeatedly to make the game run.

```
var boardLength = 50;
while (player1.position<boardLength && player2.position<boardLength) {
    gameStep(); //keep doing turns until someone wins;
}
if (player1.position>player2.position) {alert("Player1 wins!");}
else {alert("Player2 wins!");}
```

I don't know when you want the game to end, so in this example it's whoever gets to the end of the board first.  You asked a really broad question, so I tried to include lots of detail.  Please comment if you need clarification.

Comment: Wow, thanks for your time! I am using constructors, and so far it has worked ok. After reading your answer I'm more sure of what I'm doing. Thanks a lot! :D

Comment: No problem!  That wasn't the best explanation, so if you have other questions, please ask.